# Issue with sending requests to S3 bucket on AWS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using Amazon's sample code to connect to my S3 bucket. I have changed the key and bucket name for that of my bucket in S3. I have tried using the standard bucket name and using access points however I am still getting the following error.

```
Error CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers
```

I am unsure what exactly this error is saying I have missed, and also what credentials I need and how to recieve them.

I am relatively new to AWS so any help would be much appreciated.

I am running my code to access the bucket on an EC2 instance within the same VPC as the bucket so I was assuming I would not need additional permissions or credentials.

I am relatively new to AWS so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Quick search found [How can I grant my Amazon EC2 instance access to an Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket/). Also, note that S3 buckets aren't in a VPC and you always need credentials to access objects in S3 (unless they are public).

Answer (score 1):

EC2 instances use `instance profiles` (which are actually `IAM Roles`) to determine their access permissions.

What you need to do:

1. Go to `IAM`
2. Create a Role for EC2
3. Attach permissions to the Role (either create a new policy, or attach some AWS Managed policy, like `AmazonS3FullAccess` or `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` depending on if you want just read permissions or write as well)
4. Go to EC2
5. Select EC2 instance
6. `Actions -> Security - Modify IAM Role`

You can read more in AWS official documentation regarding [Instance profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html)

Answer (score 0):

This error message means your application cannot find the credentials (An access key ID, A secret access key) required to use the AWS SDK for JavaScript. As you are using the JavaScript SDK, you need to read the ***JavaScript Developer Guide*** here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-your-credentials.html